# Find Max Value and date between date range returning mutliplie records

Tags: sql, r, max

I hope someone can help me,  I been working on this all day.

I need to get max value, and the date and id where that max value is associated with between specific date ranges.

Here is my code , and I have tried many different version but it still returning more than one ID and date

```
SELECT  distinct bw_s.id,  avs.carProd, cd_s.RecordDate,

                         cd_s.milkProduction as MilkProd,
                         cd_s.WaterProduction as WaterProd

                FROM tblTest bw_s

                    INNER JOIN tblTestCp cd_s WITH(NOLOCK)
                    ON bw_s.id=cd_s.id
                   AND cd_s.recorddate BETWEEN '08/06/2014' AND '10/05/2014' 


                    Inner Join
                    ( select id, max(CarVol) as carProd
                     from tblTestCp
                    where recorddate BETWEEN '08/06/2014' AND '10/05/2014' 
                     group by  id ) avs

                     on avs.id = bw_s.id



                     order by id
```

I have table like this

```
id  RecordDate  carProd       MilkProd  WaterProd
47790   2014-10-05   132155         0   225
47790   2014-10-01   13444      0   0
47790   2014-08-06   132111     10  100
47790   2014-09-05   10000      500 145
47790   2014-09-20   10000      800 500
47791   2014-09-20   10000      300 500
47791   2014-09-21   10001      400 500
47791   2014-08-21   20001      600 500
```

And the result should be ( max carprod)

```
id  RecordDate   carProd          MilkProd  WaterProd
47790   2014-10-05   132155     0   225
47791   2014-08-21   20001      600 500
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add sample data and desired results?  I would also recommend that you put your date constants in ISO standard form of YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Why the inconsistent use of NOLOCK? You are querying the same base table multiple times but only 1 has that hint? FWIW, I would recommend not using it at all unless you are ok with periodically missing and/or duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that the name of your table is "Data":

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Data
WHERE
  Data.RecordDate BETWEEN '2014-08-21' AND '2014-10-01' 
ORDER BY
  Data.carProd DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Make sure to change the dates to match what your particular requirements are.